# Is there a point in inheriting methods from an abstract class that will always be overridden?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

The draw and resize methods from the abstract class GraphicObject are just going to be overridden every single time a another object inherits the class, so why bother even including those two methods in GraphicObject?

EDIT: I realized that the image I meant to attach didn't show up, so here it is:
[image]

Comment: Because when the non-abstract part calls them it's going to be really surprised when they're not there.

Comment: This might clear some doubts - http://www.buggybread.com/2013/07/java-importance-of-abstract-classes-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed some key concepts about Object Oriented programming and inheritance.
Suppose you have a `GraphicObject` class with `draw()` and `resize()` as **abstract methods**:

```
class GraphicObject {
    public abstract void draw();
    public abstract void resize();
}
```

Of course, these two emthod declarations does not any executable code. It simply means: *if you want to create a `GraphicObject`, you **must** provide an implementation for these methods*. But it also give a precious hint to all other classes that use `GraphicObject` instances.

Suppose you have a global `Renderer` which displays several `GraphicObject`s:

```
class Renderer {
     public void render(List<GraphicObject> objects) {
         for (GraphicObject object : objects) {
             object.draw();
         }
     }
}
```

The `render()` method calls `GraphicObject.draw()`, without knowing the implementation. Based on `GraphicObject` declaration, we **know** that an implementation exists, its signature, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's precisely to force child classes to override these methods and provide an implementation that they're left abstract in the superclass. Methods like this will probably be called by the superclass in other operations, take a look at the template method pattern for an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract class represents an *interface*. It defines the *contract* that every subclass must fulfill, i.e. offer the methods and their respective implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods, like interfaces, say "the method must exist with this signature in any real object", but leave the decision of where to implement it open.

It is fairly common for an abstract class to define some of the behaviors but not others; that's useful when a group of classes will share some behaviors but differ in others. That same rationalle may apply in subclasses of the abstract class; they may themselves be partly abstract, filling in only some of the behaviors which will be common to the classes derived from them.

It's also not uncommon to have a superclass provide a default implementation of a behavior which applies to most of its subclasses but which is overridden in some which behave differently.